# How to Create a Folder in App Folder in google drive in Android Programmatically

Tags: java, android, storage, google-drive-android-api

I am storing data in Google Drive using Google Drive API in Android programmatically. I referred to this [github](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFolderActivity.java). But it is for create a folder in Root folder not in App Folder. Is it possible to create folder in `AppFolder`?
I tried some but no result my tried code.

```
public class CreateFolderInAppFolder extends BaseDemoActivity {

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
      .setTitle("New folder").build();
    DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).createFolder(
            getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).setResultCallback(callback);
}

final ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> callback = new ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
            return;
         }
        showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
      }
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, try reading [Storing Application Data](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder):

> The App Folder is a special [folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders) that is only accessible by your application. Its content is hidden from the user and from other apps. Despite being hidden from the user, the App Folder is stored on the user's Drive and therefore uses the user's Drive storage quota. The App Folder can be used to store configuration files, temporary files, or any other types of files that belong to the user but should not be tampered with.

#### Create a file in the App Folder

> [Creating a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) in the App Folder is the same as for a normal [folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders). The following example demonstrates creating a new text file named **`appconfig.txt`** in the App Folder:

Here is a sample code:

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> contentsCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }

        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("appconfig.txt")
                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getDriveContents())
                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
    }
};
```

You can check if the file/folder is in AppFolder by retreiving  its [metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/metadata). The [**`Metadata.isInAppFolder`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Metadata.html#isInAppFolder()) method returns **`true`** if the file or folder is in the App Folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replay.Iam able to create files and retriving from App foldert but iam unable to create a folder in app folder.I  would like to save file in folder which is in app folder.

Comment: And one more doubt how to check appconfig.txt file in that folder

Comment: Hi.. @Mr.Rebot.. is that user can manually delete APP folder from drive ?